# How to call a function after closing a popover?

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I hope someone can give a beginner some guidance, my problem is this:

I have a popover window
I open that popover with a segue from the mainViewController
I want to trigger a function in the mainViewController when the popover is closed
Inside the popover I have a button to close the popover with the following code:

```
@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {checkIfPopoverDismissed()}) // I want to trigger this function in the mainView
    }
```

In the mainViewController I have the following function, that I want to be triggered by the closure of the above popover

```
 func checkIfPopoverDismissed()
    {
      print("the function is triggered")
    }
```

So with the above I get:

```
 Use of unresolved identifier 'checkIfPopoverDismissed'
```

Because obviously checkIfPopoverDismissed() is in the mainViewController and does not exist in the popover view.

Any idea how I can make this work simply?

Comment: I believe you need 'self' in the closure to let the closure know where checkIfPopoverDismissed is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use delegation to achieve that:

```
// 1. create a protocol before your PopoverViewController:
// (imagine the delegate is your helper and the protocol is the requirement of your helper)

protocol PopoverViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func popoverDidDismissed()
}

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    //2. make a delegate in your view controller
    //(you need a this helper in your class to help you...)
    weak var delegate: PopoverViewControllerDelegate?


    //...

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //3. ask the delegate to perform its function
        //(when the time is right, ask you helper to do what he is meant to do...)
        dismiss(
            animated: true, 
            completion: delegate?.popoverDidDismissed
        )
    }
}
```

Meanwhile in the mainViewController...

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? PopoverViewController {
            //4. setup the delegation
            //(say that I (mainViewController) will be the helper of destinationVC)
            destinationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

//5. Conform the protocol
//(need to meet the requirement as this helper, by having a function called popoverDidDismissed...)

extension mainViewController: PopoverViewControllerDelegate {
    func popoverDidDismissed() {
        // do what you want to do here in the main view controller,
        // this function will be called by PopoverViewController when the time is right
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what got it working in the end. now i'm going to to make an effort and learn how its working!

Comment: You are welcome. Delegation pattern is very important to iOS app development with swift. Please accept this answer if everything works, and let me know if there is any issue. good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

*Try This:

```
class MainViewController:UIViewController{

      /*In your mainViewController create an instance(I assume the name of the 
      class, you can change this accordingly)*/

     //Create a shared instance of mainVC

   static var sharedInstance:MainViewController?

   // in viewDidLoad() assign the property to self

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     MainViewController.sharedInstance = self
} 
  func checkIfPopoverDismissed()
    {
      print("the function is triggered")
    }

}


 //Assuming the class name
class PopOverView:UIViewController{

  @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {

  dismiss(self,animated: true, completion: 
   {MainViewController.sharedInstance?.checkIfPopoverDismissed()})

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to call it in the `viewWillAppear` of the `MainViewController`. Here's how:

```swift
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        checkIfPopoverDismissed()
    }
}
```

Note: If you don't want this to be called every time the `MainViewController` has appeared then you can give a check for when the popover is presented and toggle it when the popover is presented and invoke this function only when the condition is satisfied. Here's how you achieve this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var isPopoverPresented = false
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if isPopoverPresented {
            isPopoverPresented.toggle()
            checkIfPopoverDismissed()
        }
    }
    func presentPopover() {
        isPopoverPresented.toggle()
        present(PopoverController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should write a delegate to call a method from the alert or pop-over View controller to the main view controller.

Here is the example of the code:

```
// Create a protocol with set of methods
protocol AlertVCDelegate: class {
    func checkIfPopoverDismissed()
}

class AlertVC: UIViewController {
    // Create var to hold the delegate
    // Make it weak to avoid reference cycle
    weak var delegate: AlertVCDelegate!

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            // Trigger the function on the main view controller
            // through delegation
            self.delegate.checkIfPopoverDismissed()
        })
    }
}

// Conform to the Alert delegte
class MainViewController: UIViewController, AlertVCDelegate {
    let alertControllerObj = AlertVC()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Set the delegate
        // Not necessary to do it from viewWillAppear
        // Set the delegate wherever you create a instance for pop-over
        alertControllerObj.delegate = self
    }

   // Implement the method defined in the protocol
   func checkIfPopoverDismissed()
   {
     print("the function is triggered")
   }
}
```

As you are a beginner and If you want to know more about the delegates here is a nice and simple blog:
https://medium.com/@astitv96/passing-data-between-view-controllers-using-delegate-and-protocol-ios-swift-4-beginners-e32828862d3f

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an unwind segue. A feature that seems to be missed often.

Check the official documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/resource_management/dismissing_a_view_controller_with_an_unwind_segue

What the linked page does not show is that you can also control-drag from the "View Controller" icon directly to the "Exit" icon to create a manual segue you can call from code if you want to do some validation first.

[image]

In the above example, `unwindHere` was defined in the main view controller as:

```
@IBAction func unwindHere(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceVC = unwindSegue.source as? PopoverViewController {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

EDIT: The action you'd use in `PopoverViewController` could look like this:

```
@IBAction func closeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ExitPopover", sender: self)
}
```

Here, "ExitPopover" is the identifier of the unwind segue.